# New text is not written to existing file

Tags: php, file

I want to save each HTML-commandline in a file. I have a small number of users, numbered from 1 to a few hundred, so I plan to create a copy of the get-parameters in a file named 1.php, 2.php, 3.php etc.

```
function Message($T) {
  print "$T<br/>";
}

function CheckAndDelete($filename, $Delete)
{
  $res = file_exists($filename);
  if ($res) {
    Message("File \"" . $filename . "\" exist");
    if ($Delete) {
      Message("Deletes file \"" . $filename . "\"");
      unlink($filename) or die("Cannot delete file");
    }
  }
  else
    Message("File \"" . $filename . "\" does not exist");
} // CheckAndDelete()

function Check($Prompt, $fname, $fullfname, $Delete)
{
  Message($Prompt);
  CheckAndDelete($fname, $Delete);
  CheckAndDelete($fullfname, $Delete);
} // Check()

$T = strftime("%T");
$Root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
Message("Root: " . $Root);
$Owner  = $_GET[P3];

$fname = $Owner . '.php';
$fullfname = $Root . $fname;

Check("I---------------", $fname, $fullfname, TRUE);
Check("II--------------", $fname, $fullfname, TRUE);

$fil = fopen($fname, "w");
fwrite($fil, $Owner);
$S = $T . " " . $Owner;
fwrite($fil, $S);
fclose($fil);
Message($S . " Written!!");

Check("III-------------", $fname, $fullfname, FALSE);
```

This works if a file does not exist, the file is created and contains what I want them to contain. But if a file does exist, the program behaves as if everything is working okay, but the contents of the files does not change. I read something about full filenames etc on the internet, and tried to test this, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: this screams to me, use a database.

Comment: @PoulKristensen did you manage to resolve this or do you have any further questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file with the `w` mode:

```
$fil = fopen($fname, "w");
```

The PHP docs for [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for this mode states (emphasis mine):

> 'w'   Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You are overwriting the file instead of appending to it. Use an appropriate mode for appending instead; e.g: `fopen($fname, 'a');`

There's a full list of modes in the `fopen()` docs.

Alternatively, you can use the slightly higher level function [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with the `FILE_APPEND` flag; e.g:

```
$fil = file_put_contents($fname, $S, FILE_APPEND);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Darrah
Yes, its working now. I didn't answer you, because it said here that I should avoid thanks you's and stuff. But thank you anyway. ;)

Comment: By the way, do you know of any descriptions of how to use StackOverflow, like how to answer, how to close a thread and normal protocol? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah excellent. Glad to hear it worked. If you found the answer useful you can mark it as answered (although I am not sure if you need a minimum amount of reputation points to do that).

Comment: Anyway, a good place to start learning about SO is the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and after that, have a look at some of the topics in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Usually, new members are encouraged to read the section [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) although I think you did a good job here. I edited your question slightly for clarity, which is pretty common on SO. It just helps future readers who might be searching for a solution to the same problem :)